# same project different solution sign configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, strongname, strong-named-key

I am trying to find way to use the strong name sign as an configuration.
My case is: I have project that it include in two different solution.
For one solution I want that the project will be sign with strong name key, but for the other solution I want that the project will be without sign.

Currently I declare the signing throw: project->properties->signing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it, just edit proj file manually

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(SolutionName)' == 'SolutionToSign' ">
    <snip />
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <DelaySign>false</DelaySign>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>key.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```